# xslt convert date, separated node

Tags: xml, date, xslt, formatting

On xml I have in level3

```
<IncorporationDate>
  <CCYY>2016</CCYY>
  <MM>04</MM>
  <DD>21</DD>
</IncorporationDate>
```

now I need to display this as 21 April 2016

So I try concat this and use format-date but get error as try to format string.

```
<xsl:variable name="incorpDate">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(//a:Identification/b:IncorporationDate/c:DD,'/',//a:Identification/b:IncorporationDate/c:MM,'/',//a:Identification/b:IncorporationDate/c:CCYY)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then

```
 <xsl:value-of select="format-date($incorpDate, '[D] [MNn] [Y0001]')" />
```

I try format-date on whole node

```
 <xsl:value-of select="format-date(//a:Identification/b:IncorporationDate, '[D] [MNn] [Y0001]')" />
```

I know this is probably simple but xml/xslt it's not something what I know, I learn this as need to change lot's of stylesheets.

Comment: Can you say what error you are actually getting? Also, can you confirm you are using XSLT 2.0, as `format-date` is not available in XSLT 1.0? Thanks!

Comment: when first option with variable I get error:
Invalid date "21/04/2016" (Non-numeric year component
when second option with direct 
Invalid date "20160421" (Too short)
And I'm using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Create an `xs:date` and then format that:

```
<xsl:template match="IncorporationDate">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date(concat(CCYY, '-', MM, '-', DD)), '[D] [MNn] [Y0001]')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Complete sample

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="IncorporationDate">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date(concat(CCYY, '-', MM, '-', DD)), '[D] [MNn] [Y0001]')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXm/1

Answer (score 0):

I know what I done wrong.

On concat I should make a format YYYY-MM-DD so format-date function will work.

I change this and it's working.